# Installing libraries via pip is taking forever. Raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: python, pi-3b+, python-3, pip

I tried to install scipy using `pip3 install scipy` as well as `sudo pip3 install scipy` and it got stuck at `Building wheel for scipy` for 45 minutes. Same is the case for cython.

What is the fix or it just takes that long. numpy and other libraries like argparse etc took 1-2 minutes.

Using Raspberry Pi 3b+ (Newbie to Raspberry)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building scipy from source takes about 1hr20. Pre-compiled wheels are available from [piwheels.org](https://www.piwheels.org/), so you can install it from there without building yourself.

Raspbian Stretch is pre-configured to use piwheels. Are you on an older Raspbian version or another distribution? See piwheels.org for info on how to configure your system to use it or try:

```
sudo pip3 install scipy --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

Comment: I am on stretch. Thankfully scipy build was completed a few minutes after I posted the question.